# How to reuse components in xml views

Tags: sapui5

The developer-guide states "Components are independent and reusable parts used in SAPUI5 applications." but it does not give an example of how to reuse one component in another.

Specifically, I have a component which I want to reuse in different applications. This component has a backing OData-service and a view implementing the UI, and also a controller for encapsulated functions. I have no problems instantiating the component in the applications (which are of course components themselves), but I'm stuck with how I can include the compontent's view in the xml definition of the application. The developer-guide mentions a ComponentContainer as a wrapping control, but I have found no examples on how to use this.

Note that I do know how to reuse fragments or views, but my case seems different since my view is tightly bound to the OData-service (data-binding) of the component.

Any pointer to sample code is highly appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this might be helpful: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/18/2ab413eb54433eb16f1ecf15a00651/content.htm

Comment: No, that page is about placing a top-level ComponentContainer into a page using java-script. Nothing about XML or reusing a component.

Comment: Where exactly does it say that one should be able to put a component directly into an XML view?

Comment: The developer-guide says: "The ComponentContainer control wraps a UI component. You use the ComponentContainer control in the SAPUI5 control tree in the same way as any other control.". And since I can place "any other control" into the xml view definition of an application, I would also like to do that with my ComponentContainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says, you will need a ComponentContainer to wrap the component you want to load. The app that uses the component depends on it.

So the first thing to do is to register your component to the app via the manifest:

```
{
  ...
  "sap.ui5": {
    "dependencies": {
      "components": {
        "your.component.name": {
            "minVersion": "1.0.3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
...
}
```

Afterwards you can write a core:ComponentContainer tag (core: for the namespace sap.ui.core) into your XMLView. The ComponentContainer control gives you the possibility to provide the component of choice via the attributes component and name. Here's a link to the API for the [ComponentContainer](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer.html#constructor)

```
<core:ComponentContainer
    name="your.component.name"
    height="auto"
    component="your.component.name">
</core:ComponentContainer>
```

Comment: I tried this xml before, but the dependencies part was the missing link and after adding it the component loads. The next problem: how can I get the component of the ComponentContainer? The getComponent() method is no help, it returns an ID, and feeding this into sap.ui.component returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

WIth SAPUI5 1.50+ some new feature were introduced allowing you to do the following (usages are declared in the manifest.json):

```
<core:ComponentContainer
    id="compOld"
    name="nabi.demo.comp.reuse.northwind.customer.selectionBtn"
    async="true"
    componentCreated="onComponentCreated"/>

<core:ComponentContainer
    id="compNew1"
    usage="simpleCustomerSelectionBtn1"
    async="true"
    componentCreated="onComponentCreated"/>

<core:ComponentContainer
    id="compNew2"
    usage="simpleCustomerSelectionBtn2"
    async="true"
    componentCreated="onComponentCreated"/>
```

For details see here: [Implementing Re-use Components in SAPUI5 libraries and consuming them in SAPUI5 apps](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/implementing-re-use-components-in-sapui5-libraries-and-consuming-them-in-sapui5-apps)

Answer (score 0):

take a look in the SAPUi5 documentation in the part of createComponent it's described how to define component usages in manifest.json:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Component

or better take a look in the documentation "Nesting Components" and read the chapter "Declarative usage". It explains how to integrate Components in XML Views.

Another helpful SAP Blog is https://answers.sap.com/questions/327789/multiple-components-routing-inside-a-child-compone.html. It explains a little bit the architecture of nesting components and how the routing from parent to child components work.